# Check if word contains alphanumeric

Tags: php, regex

```
$str = 'This is a string with alphanumeric chars @ (test-exclude)';
```

To check on a string, I understand its `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/` but I need to check on each word of a string and exclude those words from selection.

In the above string, I need it to exlude the `@` and `(test-exclude)`.

Edit: Sure, I could loop through each word and process, but looking for an elegant way cause I'm already doing this:

```
array_unique(
  array_filter(
    explode(' ',
      preg_replace("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", ' ',
        implode(' ',
          array_map('strtolower',
            array_column( iterator_to_array($Cursor), 'description')
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: split on white space and remove those values that contain a non-word character.

Comment: It seems you want to only get alphanumeric char sequences in between whitespace, so, you can use [`preg_match_all('~(?<!\S)[A-Z0-9]+(?!\S)~i', $s, $matches)`](https://regex101.com/r/rIxuVs/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`explode` on white space then do an inverted `preg_grep`:

```
print_r(preg_grep("/[^a-z0-9]/i", explode(' ', $str), PREG_GREP_INVERT));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => This
    [1] => is
    [2] => a
    [3] => string
    [4] => with
    [5] => alphanumeric
    [6] => chars
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match_all` to return multiple matches. Those matches can include an alphanumeric word encapsuled in spaced or anchored at the start or end of the string:

```
<?php

$str = 'This is a ^*&^*&^@$ string with alphanumeric chars @ (test-exclude)';

preg_match_all('/(?:^|\s)([a-z0-9]+)(?=$|\s)/i', $str, $matches);

$cleanedstr = implode($matches[1], ' ');

echo $cleanedstr;
```